# Angular nested object

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display an object attribute nested in another object. Each employee has a category. I manage to display employees attributes but not the `category.name`
thanks for your help
here is the code:

model:

```
export interface Category{
id : number;
name: string;
    }

import {Category} from "./Category";

export interface Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  jobTitle: string;
  phone: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  employeeCode: string;
  active: boolean;
  category : Category;
}
```

service:

```
  public getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/employee/all`);
  }
```

app.ts

```
public getEmployees(): void {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (response: Employee[]) => {
        this.employees = response;
        console.log(this.employees);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }}
```

html, error coming from {{employee?.category.name}}

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>{{employee?.email}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Phone : {{employee?.phone}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-briefcase float-right"></i>Active : {{employee?.active}}</li>
          <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-briefcase float-right"></i>Category : {{employee?.category.name}}</li>
```

JSON example of one object data that it received from backend:

```
 {"id":1,
"name":"ericparis",
"email":"xxxxxx.x@gmail.com",
"jobTitle":"BA",
"phone":"06xxxxxxxx",
"imageUrl":"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png",
"active":true,
"category":{"id":1,"name":"cadre"}}
```

Comment: this should work i think. try {{employee?.category | json}} to have a look at the object in the html instead of accessing the name directly

Comment: Hi, can you specify what error you face in `{{employee?.category.name}}`. I tested it is able to display the value in HTML. You may create a Minimal Reproducible Example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: are you getting any error while doing this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like one or several of the objects doesn't have a category. in this case this piece of code would fix that

```
{{employee?.category?.name}}
```

Comment: error msg was : Object is possibly 'undefined', this solves the issue.
Thanks for your help guys!